# android--nullPointerException when get item view of a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

There are several points i wanna to provide here:

1. each item of listview consists an imageButton,2 TextView and 1 imageView
2. I want to get the imageButton of the itemView in the activity via
   position rather than the click event because i wanna add a badgeView to the imageButton
3. The error information is as listed:

**--------------------error information----------------**

```
03-04 07:03:07.226: D/dalvikvm(712): GC_CONCURRENT freed 48K, 3% free 10270K/10503K, paused 8ms+7ms
03-04 07:03:07.816: D/gralloc_goldfish(712): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-04 07:03:17.307: D/AndroidRuntime(712): Shutting down VM
03-04 07:03:17.307: W/dalvikvm(712): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409961f8)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.list_1/com.example.list_1.ClinicMessage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
**03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):    at com.example.list_1.ClinicMessage.getViewByPosition(ClinicMessage.java:122)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.example.list_1.ClinicMessage.AddBadgeView(ClinicMessage.java:104)**
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at com.example.list_1.ClinicMessage.onCreate(ClinicMessage.java:49)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
03-04 07:03:17.366: E/AndroidRuntime(712):  ... 11 more
03-04 07:03:19.176: I/Process(712): Sending signal. PID: 712 SIG: 9
```

**--------------------My Code--------------------------**

```
public class ClinicMessage extends Activity {

List<HashMap<String,Object>> mList= new ArrayList();
HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap();
private ListView mListView;
private ImageButton mIBBack;
private ImageButton mIBWrite;
private ImageButton imageButtonWithBadge; 

MyBaseAdapter mBaseAdapter;
private ActionBar actionbar;
private BadgeView badge;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.list1_clinic_message);
    actionbar=getActionBar();
    actionbar.hide();

    initComponent();
    initList();
    **AddBadgeView();**
    dealWithTitleBarEvents();
    dealWithListEvents();


}

public void initComponent()
{
    mListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvClinicMessage);
    mIBBack=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibBack);
    mIBWrite=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ibWrite);

}


public void initList()
{
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        map.put("ItemLeftPic",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ib_cmsg_left));
        map.put("ItemNext", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.im_arrow));
        map.put("ItemTitle", "上海怡康家园");
        map.put("ItemText", "医生你好，本周有空吗");
        map.put("ItemTime", "14/12/14 17:30");
        mList.add(map);
    }

    Toast.makeText(ClinicMessage.this, mList.size()+"项",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void AddBadgeView()
{
    **View view=getViewByPosition(0, mListView);**


    ImageButton imageButtonWithBadge=(ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ibClinicMessageLeft);


    badge=new BadgeView(this, imageButtonWithBadge);
    badge.setText(5);
    badge.setBadgePosition(BadgeView.POSITION_TOP_RIGHT);
    badge.show();

}

public View getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

thanks for helping me T^T

**-------------------------added info-------------**

**perhaps i didn't put the whole code in ,but i did initialize the listView by setAdapter (you can see it in the dealWithListEvents()function and the call in oncreate().).here is the dealWithListEvents():**

```
public void dealWithListEvents()
    {
        mBaseAdapter=new MyBaseAdapter(mList, this);
        mListView.setAdapter(mBaseAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()  
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,long id) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(ClinicMessage.this, "你点击了第"+position+"项",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }   
        });
    }
```

**-----------------the MyBaseAdapter---------------------**

```
    package com.example.list_1;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater; //得到一个LayoutInfalter对象用来导入布局
private List<HashMap<String,Object>>mList;

class ViewHolder
{
    private ImageButton ibLeftPic;
    private TextView tvTitle;
    private TextView tvText;
    private TextView tvTime;
    private ImageView ivNext;

}


public MyBaseAdapter(List<HashMap<String,Object>> list,Context context) {

    this.mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.mList=list;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewholder;
    //convertView就是由于滑动被隐藏回收的ItemView
    //viewHolder就是一个来接收它的缓存
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list1_listitem_clinicmessage, null);
        viewholder=new ViewHolder();
        viewholder.ibLeftPic=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ibClinicMessageLeft);
        viewholder.ivNext=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivItemArrow);
        viewholder.tvTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvClinicMessagetTitle);
        viewholder.tvText=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvClinicMessageText);
        viewholder.tvTime=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvClinicMessageTime);
        convertView.setTag(viewholder);     
    }
    else
    {
        viewholder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewholder.ibLeftPic.setBackgroundDrawable((Drawable) mList.get(position).get("ItemLeftPic"));
    viewholder.ibLeftPic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    viewholder.ivNext.setImageDrawable((Drawable)   

    mList.get(position).get("ItemNext"));

viewholder.tvTitle.setText(mList.get(position).get("ItemTitle").toString());


viewholder.tvText.setText(mList.get(position).get("ItemText").toString());
        `     `viewholder.tvTime.setText(mList.get(position).get("ItemTime").toString());`
return convertView;
}

public void refresh(List<HashMap<String,Object>> list)
{
    list=mList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you setting adapter to your listview

Comment: Yea probably `listView.getAdapter()` causing the nullpointer since you haven't set an adapter on it. From the looks of `initList()` it seems you need to create a custom adapter for you list.

Comment: Hint `ClinicMessage.java:122`

Comment: sorry,perhaps i didn't put the whole code for it. but i did inialize the listview by setAdapter in "dealWithListEvents()"(you can see it in the oncreate function)

Comment: you are calling AddBadgeView(); before calling  dealWithListEvents(); ie you calling getview on listview before setting adapter

Comment: @PreethiRao, thank u, you're right,it worked!, but there is still some problem that i don't know why the badgeview doesn't show

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming that your initialization for the `listview` is correct.

Then the problem with your code most probably will be

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
```

You have not initialized the adapter yet and also have not set the adapter for this `listview`

```
mBaseAdapter = new MyBaseAdapter(.....);
mListView.setAdapter(mBaseAdapter);
```

**EDIT**

After posting your new code. You have to switch the order of calling the method where you initialize the `adapter` and the method you call it. Use the following order

```
dealWithListEvents();
AddBadgeView();
```

Comment: sorry ,but i did setup myBaseAdapter ,perhaps i didn't show it in my question.
please see the bottom of the question ,i have added some more info to it.

Comment: @lizlalala you are trying to use the `adapter` in `AddBadgeView()` method before calling the method that initialize the `adapter` in your method `dealWithListEvents();` ... Just call it before use it

Comment: your order should change,dealWithListEvents() first~~

Comment: Yes, @lizlalala .. but I have explained it and I guess u know what I'm talking about..Always make sure to initialize the anything probably before using it

Comment: ,i  will remember that,thk u:), but the badge view doesn't show,could you give some advice?

Comment: Actually @lizlalala I have not worked with the custom BadgeView that you are dealing with. I prefer to implement it by myself using `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` and control its visibility and its value according to my needs

Answer (score 0):

You are manually adding items to your listview without using an adapter. Which is completely wrong.

You need to setup a custom Adapter for your listview,Then your `getViewByPosition(int pos, ListView listView)` method will work.

```
initComponent();
initList();
dealWithTitleBarEvents();
dealWithListEvents();
**AddBadgeView();**
```

try this.. Hope it works

Comment: sorry ,but i did setup myBaseAdapter ,perhaps i didn't show it in my question,please see the question again and see some more info i have added,thx :)